# file not uploading in mysql using php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, file, codeigniter, upload

Following is my code to upload a file in mysql database using codeigniter framework.
It has some logical errors which I am unable to find.Please help me to find it.

```
function manage_prescription($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('laboratorist_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login', 'refresh');

    if ($param1 == 'create_diagnosis_report') {
        $data['report_type']     = $this->input->post('report_type');
        $data['document_type']   = $this->input->post('document_type');



        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/diagnosis_report/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
        $data['file_name'] = $_POST["userfile"]["name"];

        $data['prescription_id'] = $this->input->post('prescription_id');
        $data['description']     = $this->input->post('description');
        $data['timestamp']       = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . date('H:i:s'));
        $data['laboratorist_id'] = $this->session->userdata('laboratorist_id');

        $this->db->insert('diagnosis_report', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('diagnosis_report_created'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?laboratorist/manage_prescription/edit/' . $this->input->post('prescription_id'), 'refresh');
    }

    if ($param1 == 'delete_diagnosis_report') {
        $this->db->where('diagnosis_report_id', $param2);
        $this->db->delete('diagnosis_report');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('diagnosis_report_deleted'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?laboratorist/manage_prescription/edit/' . $param3, 'refresh');

    } else if ($param1 == 'edit') {
        $page_data['edit_profile'] = $this->db->get_where('prescription', array(
            'prescription_id' => $param2
        ))->result_array();
    }
    $page_data['page_name']     = 'manage_prescription';
    $page_data['page_title']    = get_phrase('manage_prescription');
    $page_data['prescriptions'] = $this->db->get('prescription')->result_array();
    $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

When I run this code it gives no error. But, it do not stores the file also.and also it shows file_name in database as NULL.

Comment: can you add your view code?

Comment: ok I will add my View code @kumar_v

Comment: No. Edit your question and add.

Comment: No need to ask as new question. You can edit this question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You need to use `$_FILES["userfile"]` instead of `$_POST`

```
$data['file_name'] = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
```

instead of

```
$data['file_name'] = $_POST["userfile"]["name"];
```

Comment: I did the same u told.But, still the problem exist !

Comment: can you check you getting `$param1` value properly inside the function!